# How to update objects nested in React state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have a function that updates my nested objectin React state, and i have a working solution, but im looking for something more polished.

so this is my state structure:

```
state: {
  ...someState,
  object: [
      {
        key1: "1",
        key: "2",
        key3: "3",
        key4: "4"},
      {
        key1: "1",
        key: "2",
        key3: "3",
        key4: "4"}]
    }
```

Currently im using this function to update the state:

```
handleInputChange = (
    e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    name: FilterKeys,
    subname?: any,
    index?: number
  ) => {
    e.persist();

      if (subname && index !== undefined) {
        let prop: SomeKeys;
        prop = subname;
        const editedObject = Object.assign({}, this.state.object);
        editedObject[index][prop] = e.target.value;
        const object = Object.keys(editedObject).map((e: any) => {
          return editedObject[e];
        });
        this.setState(
          (prevState: I) => ({
            ...prevState,
            object
          }),
          () => {
            this.someCallback()
          }
        );

    }
  };
```

My goal is to do something like this:

```
 handleInputChange = (
    e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    name: FilterKeys,
    subname?: any,
    index?: number
  ) => {
    e.persist();

      if (subname && index !== undefined) {
        let prop: SomeKeys;
        prop = subname;
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
          object: [...prevState.object, prevState.object[index][prop]:3]
})
}

    }
  };
```

I hope you understand what im getting at. I am also aware of a solution where i could assign some key to the object, so i can access it that way, but i was interested in syntax like this, cause imo it looks much cleaner

p.s Length of object array is user dependent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update `key3` from `object[0]` only:

```
const newState = {
    ...state,
    object:[
        ...state.object,
        [0] : {
            ...state.object[0],
            key3: newValue
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: when i try to use [index]:, there is red line saying that "," is expected

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the third party libraries? 
I recommend https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set. As you  need to have immutable state, you can use lodash/fp (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```
import set from 'lodash/fp/set'

//...
this.setState(
  currentState => set(['object', index, prop], e.target.value, currentState)
)
```

`set` is lodash.fp function. The First argument is a path of the property to set, the second one is a new value, the third one is an object to update. Lodash/fp always creates a NEW object.

If you understand functional programming, curring, you can reduce this construction to

```
this.setState(
      set(['object', index, prop], e.target.value)
    )
```

---

**Another solution**

Of course, you can do it without external libraries:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    object: [
        ...prevState.object.slice(0, index),
        {
            ...prevState.object[index],
            [prop]: e.target.value,
        },
        ...prevState.object.slice(index + 1),
    ],    
}))
```

Comment: I would prefer not to import lodash into this, even though its cherry picked function. This method with slice is closest to my initial thought as it can get. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite as concise as you hoped but I think this should do the trick.

It maps the original array into an array of new objects, if the index matches the current iteration then it will overwrite the value for the given "key" to the value from the event target.

```
handleInputChange = (
  e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
  name: FilterKeys,
  subname?: any,
  index?: number
) => {
  e.persist();

  if (subname && index !== undefined) {
    const prop: SomeKeys = subname;
    const newObjArray = this.state.object
      .map((obj, i) =>  ({
        ...obj,
        [prop]: i !== index ? obj[prop] : event.target.value
      }));

    this.setState((prevState)=>{
      object: newObjArray
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is close to my original solution(in terms of lines of code etc), so it does not work for me

Comment: They're not the same...

Currently, you are not treating `this.state.object` immutably. You assign the array to an object but the elements (objects) are still the same references to before the assigning since they weren't also reassigned. Therefore, any change you make to a key will be present in the previous object as you are using the same reference. State should be treated as immutable.

Also, there are no conversions from `array -> object` then `object -> array`. They might be similar in length but they actually do it very differently!

Comment: Yeah, i found that out in the meantime. Thanks for the explanation anyways. However i still decided to go with spreading prevstate, instead of creating new objects. Whats weird to me, is that i could have sworn  that i saw example that i used on official React docs page, but maybe their example was a bit different than mine. Anyway, thanks again :)

Comment: No worries at all, glad to hear you got a solution!